# Logging in with Facebook through Parse error after updating to Xcode 6.3

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform, syntax-error, xcode6.3

I used a tutorial to learn how to log in with Facebook through Parse and followed it step by step. The link to the tutorial is: http://blog.oskoui-oskoui.com/?p=8161
It worked great in Xcode 6.2 and I had no problems with my code, but now after updating to Xcode 6.3 I am getting an error that says: "missing argument for parameter 'selector' in call". This error appears right after "PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions" in the code below. I have tried a few different things and all I get is a different error. How can I fix this?

```
    let permissions = ["public_profile"]



    @IBAction func facebookLogInButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(permissions: permissions, {

        (user: PFUser!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if user == nil {

            NSLog("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")

        } else if user.isNew {

            NSLog("User signed up and logged in through Facebook! \(user)")

        } else {

            NSLog("User logged in through Facebook! \(user)")

        }

    })

}
```

Comment: Parse has changed their syntax slightly and provides a new Facebook Util framework. You need to update and look at the new documentation

Answer (score 0):

This could be a case of Xcode misreading an error. At the beginning of the closure, the two variables should have "?" instead of "!".  The code would be

```
(user:PFUser?, error:NSError?) in
```

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the problem.

```
@IBAction func fbLoginClick(sender: AnyObject) {

    PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(self.permissions, block: {

        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if user == nil {

            NSLog("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")

        } else if user!.isNew {

            NSLog("User signed up and logged in through Facebook! \(user)")

        } else {

            NSLog("User logged in through Facebook! \(user)")

        }

    })

}
```